# pyqt on Google App engine

Tags: google-app-engine, pyqt

I want to know if there is any way I can deploy a pyqt based python GUI application on google app engine. As per the FAQ, it says that app engine can support only pure python libraries but I wanted to use the sophisticated graphics features of pyqt which I am using for my desktop python application.

Is there a any other way ?

Many thanks in advance

Shyam

Comment: If the program is running on GAE, on some far-away server in the cloud, how do you suppose it would display its GUI on your desktop? It cannot, of course.

Comment: I am talking about the way the google apps like docs and spreadsheets work on the cloud. They have a GUI so I believe there must be a way to render GAE apps on the browser just like the standard google apps . - Shyam

Comment: That's all done in Javascript, running on the client. Check out, for example, [Google Web Toolkit](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/)

Comment: Ok , so as I understand , I can have the business logic running as python on GAE and that can trigger the client to render using javascript on the browser . Is that correct ? - Shyam

Comment: Pretty much. Generally the server doesn't *trigger* things to happen in the browser, but rather the Javascript in the browser runs the show. But yes, GUI in Javascript in the browser, business logic in GAE.

Comment: @ Ernest Friedman-Hill - Thanks a lot for clarifying. I was wondering that we can do a java applet like GUI app and put it in GAE which can then be rendered on the browser. That was my assumption and hence the confusion. - Shyam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

PyQt is used to build desktop UIs. It cannot be used to build browser-based UIs. This has nothing to do with App Engine.

Comment: Sorry Folks

I was under the impression that we can have a java applet like GUI on GAE and have it rendered and run on the browser. That was my silly assumption and hence the confusion.

Can the javascript support animations ??

- Shyam

Comment: This, again, has nothing to do with App Engine. You can emit any javascript you like; how it behaves is dependent on the visitor's browser.

Comment: Thanks a lot. One final thing. Is there any way we can make a desktop application ( instead of browser ) interact with a app running on the  app engine ? - Shyam

Comment: Two things, NaCL (native client) allows untrusted code to be ran in a sandbox environment. This would allow this to happen, though it is highly experimental. And the other is that pyqt can be used to generate the data, used as a library that GAE uses, like Qt Models, instead of Django Models, but this way, still need to output to html and send that.

Comment: You can certainly use a desktop app instead of a browser to communicate with App Engine. Your desktop app just needs to be able to send HTTP requests, and your App Engine app should probably expose an API, using something like ProtoRPC.